# Replace Statistics_analysis with SearchCursor?

Tags: arcpy, arcmap, cursor, performance, statistics

*I'm using ArcGIS 10.3, 64bit with an advanced license.* I have the following code, that runs just fine. It goes through a table that contains a large number of entries with zip-codes and population information. There are multiple entries for each zip-code. I now want to:

- Go through the whole table and select each unique zip code one by one and
- calculate the mean value of the population entries

I therefore created the following script:

```
import arcpy

# set workspace
workspace = r"Path_to_my_WS"
arcpy.env.workspace = workspace
arcpy.env.scratchworkspace = workspace
arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True

# set inputs
inputTable = r"Path_to_my_table"
field_zip = "Fieldname_with_zipcodes"
field_pop = "Fieldname_with_population"

# create list with unique zip-codes
zipcodes = [row[0] for row in arcpy.da.SearchCursor(inputTable, field_zip)]
uniqueZipcodes = set(zipcodes)

# MAIN TASK: SUM SALES
# empty list to append values to
pop_avg = []
arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(inputTable, "inputTable_Lyr")
# Loop through unique zip codes and perform statistics analysis
for each_zipcode in uniqueZipcodes:
    where_clause = "field_pop =" + each_zipcode
    arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management("inputTable_Lyr","NEW_SELECTION", where_clause)
    statistics = """{0}\statistics""".format(workspace)
    arcpy.Statistics_analysis("inputTable_Lyr",statistics,[[field_pop,"MEAN"]])
    inquiry_pop_avg = arcpy.da.SearchCursor(statistics,"MEAN_field_pop")
    pop_avg.append(inquiry_pop_avg)
    del statistics
print(uniqueZipcodes)
print(pop_avg)
```

It does work like this, however it takes a rather long time. Would it be possible to replace the `arcpy.Statistics_analysis()` function with a more performant version of the `arcpy.da.SearchCursor()` in order to avoid creating and deleting a table for each loop?

Comment: I think it would be much quicker and simpler to use a `case_field` (`field_zip`) with Summary Statistics.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use list comprehensions and cursors to do something like this:

```
def pop_avg(pop_info):
     zipcode_info = {}
     for zp in pop_info:
         try:
            zipcode_info[zp[0]].append(zp[1])
         except:
            zipcode_info[zp[0]] = [zp[1]]
     return [(key,sum(value)/float(len(value))) for key,value in sorted(zipcode_info.iteritems())]
```

**Using the sample dataset below:**

[image]

- populate a list with zip, population pairs.
- `pop_stats = [(row[0],row[1]) for row in arcpy.da.SearchCursor("PopData",["ZIPCODE","POPULATION"])]`
- Call the **pop_avg** function and pass it **pop_stats**
- the sample data produces the results below:

[image]

- The same results can be obtained by simply using summary statistics:

[image]